# Remove folder from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this bit of code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Right now, if I access `www.oldomain.com/files/document.pdf` it redirects me to `archive.newdomain.com/files/document.pdf`.

This is not what I want. I need to get redirected to `archive.newdomain.com/document.pdf` *(whitout the /files/ folder)*.

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost doing that already, just change it to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.newdomain.com%1 [R=301,L]
```

Using `%1`, which you were already capturing but not using.

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing since the previous redirects that you visited will be cached.